# Facebook share link and reward only users who have the app installed, it is possible?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to obtain this flow with facebook and ios:

- A user download my app from the App Store
- The user click a button "share",and it will share, with Graph, a link on the user wall
- A friend of his user click on the link he just shared and it will be redirect to the itunes store. He download my app.
- The user that share the link, click another button on the app, something like: "click to check if some friends had download the app under your suggestion"
- The app get the friends list of the user with a call to `me/friends`. The endpoint returns me only the user friends how are using the app (so the friends how have my app installed...)
- if i found at least one friend in this list i reward (only one time) the user how have share the link. The reward is a blocked functionality of the app.

I know that platform policy of facebook said :

> “Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.”

but it explain also this [concept](https://external-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAgbSPFHr8mpJ3r&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-xfa1%2Ft39.2178-6%2F851566_549981185101135_1548011715_n.png)
So it seems that i can reward a user for real download of the app... What is the correct interpretation? With the flow i have just write my app will pass the facebook review?

Comment: AFAIK you are only allowed to reward the user for successful game invites: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests // By having your users post on their timeline, and reward them for that if it leads to one of their friends joining the app, you would encourage people to post stuff they otherwise likely would not have posted – and that is what Facebook does not want. Timeline posts should only ever be made because the user wants to share something with their friends, but not because it is connected to any kind of rewards – because that just leads to spam posts.

Comment: thanks again. if you write an answer i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you are only allowed to reward the user for successful game invites: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests

By having your users post on their timeline, and reward them for that if it leads to one of their friends joining the app, you would encourage people to post stuff they otherwise likely would not have posted – and that is what Facebook does not want.
Timeline posts should only ever be made because the user wants to share something with their friends, but not because it is connected to any kind of rewards – because that just leads to spam posts.